# Once I select the word, how it can be instantaneously displayed in the label?

Tags: ocaml

```
open Tk;;
let top = openTk ()
let _ = Wm.title_set top "Listbox 2"
let v = Textvariable.create ();;
Textvariable.set v " ? " ;;
let l = Label.create ~textvariable:v
    ~background:(`Color "#FDF1B8")
    ~foreground:(`Color "#0F056B")
    top
let mylist = Listbox.create
    ~selectmode:`Single 
    ~background:(`Color "#FF7F00")
    ~foreground:(`Color "#3F2204")
    ~selectbackground:(`Color "#BEF574")
    ~selectforeground:(`Color "#095228")
    top
let some_composers = ["Mozart";"Chopin";
              "Beethoven";"Verdi";"Bizet"]
let _ = Listbox.insert
    ~index:`End
    ~texts:some_composers
    mylist
let b = Button.create ~text:"Show selected composer"
    ~command:(fun () ->
      try
    let n = match (List.hd (Listbox.curselection mylist)) with
    | `Num y -> y
    | _ -> failwith "No Selection"
    in
    Textvariable.set v (List.nth some_composers n)
      with _ -> (print_endline "No Selection"; flush stdout)
         )
    top
let bq = Button.create ~text:"Quit"
    ~command:(fun () ->
         print_endline "Bye."; flush stdout; closeTk ())
    top;;
pack [l];;
pack [mylist];;
pack [b];;
pack [bq];;
let _ = Printexc.print mainLoop ()
```

[image]

The above code is very simple. It allows to select a particular musician in the listbox, press the button under the listbox, then the name of the musician is displayed in the label at the top of the window.

Instead of using a button, I would like to remove the button, and when I select the name of the musician, it will be instantaneously display in the label above the windows.

Is there a right way to do that?

**ATTEMPT**

```
open Tk;;
let top = openTk ()
let _ = Wm.title_set top "Listbox 2"
let v = Textvariable.create ();;
Textvariable.set v " ? " ;;

let mylist = Listbox.create
    ~selectmode:`Single 
    ~background:(`Color "#FF7F00")
    ~foreground:(`Color "#3F2204")
    ~selectbackground:(`Color "#BEF574")
    ~selectforeground:(`Color "#095228")
    top
let some_composers = ["Mozart";"Chopin";
              "Beethoven";"Verdi";"Bizet"]
let _ = Listbox.insert
    ~index:`End
    ~texts:some_composers
    mylist

let n = List.hd (Listbox.curselection mylist) in
Textvariable.set v (List.nth some_composers n);
let l = Label.create 
    ~textvariable:(Textvariable.get mylist)
    ~background:(`Color "#FDF1B8")
    ~foreground:(`Color "#0F056B")
    top

let bq = Button.create ~text:"Quit"
    ~command:(fun () ->
         print_endline "Bye."; flush stdout; closeTk ())
    top;;
pack [l];;
pack [mylist];;
pack [bq];;
let _ = Printexc.print mainLoop ()
```

Comment: (Just a small nomenclatural comment: not every bit of functionality is a "workaround". At least I don't look at it that way. :-) A workaround is what you use when there's no good way to do something but you need to do it anyway. I suspect there's a perfectly good way to do what you want here.)

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are right.  You said "there's a perfectly good way to do what you want here". Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: I'll take a look. I was doing lots of tcl/tk coding a few months ago (not in OCaml). So I have some experience to draw on. But somebody with even more recent experience might jump in before I figure it out....

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I have made an attempt. I am pretty sure I am not that far from a good answer, but it doesn't work. Do you have time to check it out now?

Comment: I have obligations until quite a few hours from now. I don't see any calls to the `bind` function in your code. That's what you're going to need, almost certainly.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I am not sure of what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have time for a quick answer at the moment, but maybe this will help.

The default handlers for a listbox aren't going to do what you want, they just change the appearance of the item that you click on. But you can establish any desired handling for a button click using the `bind` function.

The tk `bind` function is used to specify what should happen when an event occurs in the user interface. What you want to do is to specify something that happens when button 1 (say) is clicked in the listbox. I don't have labltk installed on my system, so I can't try out this code, but it would be something roughly like this:

```
bind ~events: [`ButtonPressDetail 1] ~action: myhandler listbox
```

Before this (of course) you need to define `myhandler` to insert the desired text.

**Update**

This code works for me. Note that you want to bind to the button release event (so that the selection has already happened).

```
open Tk

let some_composers =
    ["Mozart"; "Chopin"; "Beethoven"; "Verdi"; "Bizet"]

let main () =
    let top = openTk () in
    Wm.title_set top "Listbox 2";
    let v = Textvariable.create () in
    Textvariable.set v "?";
    let l =
        Label.create
            ~textvariable: v
            ~background: (`Color "#FDF1B8")
            ~foreground: (`Color "#0F056B")
            top
    in
    let mylist =
        Listbox.create
            ~selectmode: `Single
            ~background: (`Color "#FF7F00")
            ~foreground: (`Color "#3F2204")
            ~selectbackground:(`Color "#BEF574")
            ~selectforeground:(`Color "#095228")
            top
    in
    Listbox.insert ~index: `End ~texts: some_composers mylist;
    let set_composer ev =
        match Listbox.curselection mylist with
        | [] -> () (* Not really possible *)
        | index :: _ ->
            Textvariable.set v (Listbox.get mylist index)
    in
    bind ~events: [`ButtonReleaseDetail 1]
         ~action: set_composer
         mylist;
    let bq = Button.create
        ~text: "Quit"
        ~command:
            (fun () ->
                print_endline "Bye.";
                flush stdout;
                closeTk ())
        top
    in
    pack [l];
    pack [mylist];
    pack [bq];
    Printexc.print mainLoop ()

let () = main ()
```

When I run it like this I see the behavior you want:

```
$ labltk m.ml
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Can you show me what it might look like in the code bellow? I just can see the details of `bind` in http://labltk.forge.ocamlcore.org/apiref/index.html. Does `bind` is the same thing as `pack`. To be honest, I am quite confused.

Comment: You need to understand tk if you're going to use it. The documentation that you link to here is not sufficient to understand tk. I suggest the book *Tcl and the Tk Toolkit* by Ousterhout (if it's still available--my copy is ancient). `bind` is, as I explain above, the function used to specify what should happen when the user performs various actions (typing, clicking, moving the mouse).

Comment: I provided a little snippet to understand how to do it. Are you up to modify that code with `bind` to show me how it works? To be honest, it is much more understandable, for me, when I can see how it works with an example.